# JRUBY .war file migration

Tags: apache, war, jruby

I'm planning to deploy a compiled JRuby project to Apache, the project contains migration files. Is there any way to deploy a war file with database (to be migrated) without having to install JRuby and run rake db:migrate?
Or if it's not possible, can you suggest what is the best practice in deploying .war files. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, Apache won't handle .war files a its not a JVM sever.

let's assume here that you've meant Tomcat or something similar.

- you do not need to install JRuby its packed in the .war
- you could do a `java -jar my.war -S rake db:migrate` to migrate
- alternatively you can trigger migrations as the application boots

loosely this means triggering : `ActiveRecord::Migrator.migrate ...` after Rails's initialization

Comment: Thank you, yes, I mean Tomcat I just forgot to setup the warble.rb to be runnable.